# await doesn't seem to wait till the async call is finished

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have the async function which uses `await` calls and I thought that when you use `await`, it should pause the function execution until the value it received. For some reason, it doesn't work with me.

Here's my function (it is inside a class):

```
async userExistsInDB(email) {
    let userExists;
    await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/notificator', async(err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let collection = db.collection('users');
        userExists = await collection.find({email: email}).limit(1).count() > 0;
        console.log("INSIDE:\n", userExists);
        db.close();
    });
    console.log("OUTSIDE:\n", userExists);
    return userExists;
}
```

And here's how I call it in another function inside the same class:

```
async getValidationErrors(formData) {
   let userExists = await this.userExistsInDB(formData.email);
   console.log("ANOTHER FUNC:\n", userExists);
}
```

So, I get the following output:

```
OUTSIDE:
 undefined
ANOTHER FUNC:
 undefined
INSIDE:
 true
```

although the value `INSIDE: true` I expect to get printed the first.

Basically, what I need is to get the boolean value `userExists` from the `userExistsInDB` function and use it in other code.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` only works with promises, so `MongoClient.connect(…)` would need to return a promise. Yet, you are using it as a callback API, and even with an `async` (promise-returning) callback function, which is not gonna work. Assuming mongo returns promises if you don't pass a callback, your code should look like

```
async function userExistsInDB(email) {
    let db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/notificator');
    let collection = db.collection('users');
    let userExists = (await collection.find({email: email}).limit(1).count()) > 0;
    db.close();
    return userExists;
}
```

though ideally you'd rather do

```
async function userExistsInDB(email) {
    let db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/notificator');
    try {
        let collection = db.collection('users');
        let userCount = (await collection.find({email: email}).limit(1).count();
        return userCount > 0;
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```